# hard to always remember language change excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, language

I'm used to type in 2 different languages
how can I make that when I select specific cells in excel the keyboard language should temporary change to another language

Comment: create a VBA program

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `Alt+Shift` is the simplest way to change keyboard language...